# Choice of Ruby Web Framework To Use With Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, sinatra

I'm coding a medium sized web application and am planning on making it MV*/JS based using backbone.js. I have a choice of using either Sinatra or Rails for the REST API/session based authentication. Which would you choose, and why?

Comment: This is likely to be closed since the answers will be opinion-based, which is against the guidelines. That said, Backbone was specifically written with Rails-style restful routes in mind, but will work fine with any backend. Use whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has little to do with Backbone.js, and a lot to do with the overall complexity of your application.

Rails provides many features that Sinatra does not:

- MVC architecture
- ORM framework
- Relational Database Scaffolding

If you won't benefit from these features, Sinatra is a good choice because of its minimalist design (under 2,000 lines of code).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm more familiar Sinatra combined the DataMapper ORM. Since I prefer writing my own code (coming from a PHP MVC background) rather than relying on scaffolding, I think I'll choose Sinatra.